# How to code a centered short underline?

Tags: html, css

[image: example]

I have to mockup this, and I though about 2 ways to do it:

1. Background image with the line
2. Adding another element of 1px height, with a green top/bottom border. I could even do this using the :after selector

But I'm not convinced by any of the two. The first one because it needs an extra image, and the second one because it implies adding an extra element, which won't be semantically correct.

Is there any way without adding elements or images?

Comment: Technically, using :after isn't adding an extra element. So I would suggest you're using the second approach.

Comment: What's "semantic" about an underline decoration?

Comment: well for centered underline we generally use `border-top` or `border-bottom` depends upon the situation but here i am unaware of your code so if your problem will not solve with border property i suggest you to share your code or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Paulie_D Nothing semantic about an underline decoration. What isn't semantic is having to add elements to do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I love pseudo elements so that's exactly what I would use here.

```
h1{
   position:relative;
}

h1:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   width:20%;
   border-top:1px solid green;
   bottom:0;
   left:40%;
}
```

If you want the underline to be a fixed width, you'll need to use negative margins to center it.

```
h1:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   width:100px;
   border-top:1px solid green;
   bottom:0;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-50px;
}
```